# Getting AttributeError for body tag in Json parsing Python

Tags: python, django

Getting this error when parsing data

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'body'

Generating data JSON like this

```
def test_UserEmail(self):
    # Assume
    data = {
        'params': {
            'content': {
                'mail': self.email_address
            }
        }
    }
    JsonData = json.dumps(data)

    # Action
    value = login.getUserInfobymail(JsonData)
```

I am generating this data for UnitTesting, and calling the method below.
from my test file.

```
@csrf_exempt
def getUserInfobymail(request):
#request variable will come from vue.js
    param = json.loads(request.body)
    content = param['params']['content']
    mail = content['mail']
    context = {}
```

**How to create Data properly which I can get in response.body?**

If I write param = json.loads(request) <- without .body it works well but
with response.body it gives error.
Now what should be the Json data which works with response.body?

Comment: what is `request`  here? Is that inside a view? Please add more info

Comment: [mcve] and full matching traceback plase. Obviously at the point this error is raised, `request` is a string, so check the code before.

Comment: Updated question, please check.
#request variable will come from vue.js 
@brunodesthuilliers yes that is a string, so now how to make a request in python then? there that request is coming from VUE.

Comment: Your view expects a Django `HttpRequest` object, not a string. How to test views is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/advanced/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is i have to make a post request to pass the data inside body.

For that, I had to make request like this,

```
factory = RequestFactory()
request = factory.post('post_URL', data, content_type='application/json')
```

also changed in JSON single to double 
**'**  ->  **"**